# Does python sqlite3 library need sqlite to be installed?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

There are Python libraries that allow to communicate with a database. Of course, to use these libraries there should be an installed and running database server on the computer (python cannot communicate with something that does not exist).

My question is whether the above written is applicable to the `sqlite3` library. Can one say that this library does not need any database to be installed (and running) on the computer? Can one say that `sqlite3` needs only a file system?

Answer (score 7):

SQLite only needs a filesystem, yes, it is not a *standalone* server. Instead, SQLite is an *embedded* database. The whole database driver is contained in a shared library loaded together with the Python executable, as needed.

You do need to have the `libsqlite3` shared library installed; Python itself only includes the Python integration for that library.

For Ubuntu, for example, you'd install the [libsqlite3-0 package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libsqlite3-0); but since the Python package already depends on this this is not something you need to worry about, *usually*. Mac OS X already comes with the shared library installed, and on Windows I believe the Python Windows installer bundles the library with it. The [ActiveState Python Windows distribution](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/whatsincluded.html) certainly does, for example.

If you want to compile Python from source, you'll have to install (at the very least) the SQLite development headers to enable compilation of the `sqlite3` package.

Answer (score 1):

No, **sqlite package is part of Python standard library** and as soon as you have Python installed, you may use sqlite functionality.

MartijnPieters noted, the actual shared library is not technically part of Python (this was my a bit oversimplified answer) but comes as shared library, which has to be installed too.

Practically speaking, if you manage installing Python, you have the sqlite available for your Python code.

As OP asked for for a need to install sqlite separately, I will not speculate on how to install Python, which is not able to work with it.

Comment: No, the `sqlite` shared library is **not** part of the Python distribution. You need to install it separately. Only the **Python wrapper** is part of Python.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So I would be more precise, that it gets installed with Python.

Comment: Certain installers may choose to bundle it with the installer, yes.

Comment: The headers need to be available when compiling; you can install Python **just fine** without `libsqlite3` being installed. Importing `sqlite3` will then just fail. So, practically speaking, if you managed to install Python, SQLite3 could still be missing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Python installation, which has sqlite3 wrapper without the shared library needed for real use - this I would call broken Python installation.

Comment: There are plenty of other libraries bundled with Python that require an extra shared library to be installed. In all likelihood, you don't have them all. That doesn't make your Python installation broken, however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Which one do you mean? Python claims to have "batteries included", missing shared library required by some stdlib package is definitely missing battery and makes the installation broken.

Comment: I see why you think that, but that's not how it works. That's a good think, as it makes the Python project distribution much leaner.

Comment: It depends on your exact OS and how Python was installed, but examples include many packages in the [multimedia category](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mm.html), any of the specific DBM packages in the [persistence category](https://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html), plus any of the OS-specific modules; these all could be included in a *binary* installer without the requisite shared libraries being present on the target system.